# How can i provide roleassignment at subscription level using ARMtemplate?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-managed-identity

I am new to arm template. I have created the following armtemplate to assign the role at subscription level using managed identities.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "resources": [
{
      "type": "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities",
      "apiVersion": "2023-01-31",
      "name": "managedidentityPOC",
      "location": "<location>"
    }
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
            "apiVersion": "2022-04-01",
            "name": "[guid(resourceGroup().id)]",
            "scope": "[concat('/subscriptions/',subscription().subscriptionId)"
            "properties": {
                "roleDefinitionId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', 'acdd72a7-3385-48ef-bd42-f606fba81ae7')]",
                "principalId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', managedidentityPOC)).principalId]"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have created a managed identity and trying to give a roleassignment with a scope of subscription.
But getting below error:

The resource namespace 'subscriptions' is invalid. (Code: InvalidResourceNamespace)

Answer (score 0):

Please try by changing the following line of code:

```
"scope": "[concat('/subscription/',subscriptions().subscriptionId)"
```

to

```
"scope": "[concat('/subscriptions/',subscriptions().subscriptionId)"
```

Basically the scope should be `/subscriptions/<subscription-id>` and not `subscription/<subscription-id>`.

Comment: it is throwing the same error with subscriptions : The resource namespace 'subscriptions' is invalid. (Code: InvalidResourceNamespace)